# Deriving a model of a point-driven Chladni plate

Tags: classical-mechanics, computational-physics, oscillators, vibrations, anharmonic-oscillators

Please note — this question considers a *point-driven* Chladni plate, *not* Chladni's classical experiment. I'm aware of various other questions concerning the latter here on Physics.SE.

---

As the title suggests, I'm looking to derive a physically correct model of a point-driven Chladni plate. Essentially, this is a plate (typically square or circular, but it can be of any shape) attached to a rod which is oscillating (up/down) according to a sine wave with a given frequency and amplitude.

The included photo of my setup below shows what happens to the plate at a series of specific frequencies — the nodal lines, i.e. the positions on the plate that are not oscillating (due to interference), can be visualised by sprinkling small particles (in this case, kitchen salt) on the plate.
In addition, the anti-nodes, i.e. the positions on the plate with the (locally) largest oscillations, can be visualised by sprinkling even smaller particles on the plate (in this case, the finest particles in the kitchen salt). Though the latter is certainly an interesting phenomenon (and admittedly somewhat counter-intuitive), let us focus only on the nodal lines in the remainder.

[image]

Studying an oscillating plate points in the direction of either Kirchhoff-Love (thin plates) or Reissner-Mindlin (also thicker plates) plate theory (and in fact, there is some recent literature on this in this very context). However, I'm wondering whether it is possible to come up with an "easier" model describing the nodal lines. After all, what we have is a plate with a (circular) hole. The up/down movement of the boundary of this hole is simply the given sine function (frequency/amplitude). The rest of the plate gradually follows this movement, but depends on the stiffness/inertia of the plate. Eventually, the waves on the plate start to interfere, resulting in nodes and anti-nodes. This happens at any frequency, though only at certain frequencies are these steady in the sense that they are not a function of time. It is these frequencies (or rather, the nodal lines associated with those) I'm interested in.

The simplest case would be to consider an isotropic material, though in practise the material is most likely orthotropic (e.g. due to rolling or extrusion). The photo included above supports this statement — after all, for a symmetric and isotropic plate, the resulting nodal lines should be similarly symmetric. Nevertheless, let us assume an isotropic material for now.

With this in mind, would it make (physical) sense to consider a dense grid representing the plate, with  points following the up/down movement of their neighbouring point(s) with a certain delay (representing the stiffness/inertia of the plate)? The nodal lines then correspond to the zero level sets of the vertical movement. If these do not change after a certain initialisation time, we are in a steady setting.

In this grid scenario, there are several remaining questions — what about the "reflection" of the waves at the boundaries of the plate, and what about the energy involved (not all energy will go in the propagation of the waves)?

Another approach would be to replace the grid by a continuum, and use e.g. finite element analysis (though I do not directly see how). However, perhaps this goes too much into the direction of the numerical aspect of the problem, which might not be suitable to discuss in detail on this SE.

Comment: Naive question: what is wrong with the following approach? i) Write out the differential equation for the system ii) Impose boundary conditions (the plate's edges are free) and iii) Solve the equation numerically on a computer. The equations are not too hard for an isotropic plate, and the method seems relatively straightforward.

Comment: @Philip Indeed, that would usually be my approach. However, the choice of plate theory (Kirchhoff-Love, Reissner-Mindlin, ...) seems to complicate matters here. But you seem to have something in mind (PDE), any further thoughts on that?

Comment: Well the partial differential equation doesn't seem *that* bad. Taking the Kirchhoff-Love model, it's a fourth order equation in space. I assume it can be solved on *Mathematica* relatively painlessly. Are you constrained by any particular programming language? **EDIT:** Hm, apparently I spoke too soon. Apparently  *Mathematica*'s finite element methods can't handle equations with higher than second-order derivatives in the spatial variables, but it has other methods that can.

Comment: Indeed, Kirchhoff-Love comes with the challenge that it needs $C^1$ basis functions in a FEM context. It might also not be the right choice, depending on the thickness of the plate. Reissner-Mindlin yields a second-order PDE, but comes with different numerical challenges (e.g. locking) in a FEM context. Hence the question whether the nodal lines can be described/modelled in a different way :).

Comment: Fantastic picture - I have an idea of how to do this and will try to put an answer up in the next couple of days

Comment: @tom Thank you! In the meantime I got rid of the salt as it was absorbing too much water... I'll probably replace it with fine grained sand. I'm looking forward to your answer — the bounty I set on this question is running out though.

Comment: sorry running out of time, yes - when I used these fine sand was the thing to use#

Comment: @tom Despite the expired bounty, I hope you'll still have some time to write down your thoughts on modelling the behaviour of these point-driven plates.

Comment: @Ailurus it is on my to do list, but that is rather long at the moment :-(    do remind me from time to time and it will come, sorry for the wait

Comment: @Ailurus - sorry still on the to do list... :-(

Comment: @Ailurus sorry, do ping again in a few weeks if not up...